# Angular: изменение в DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Приветствую!

Начал изучать Angular и столкнулся с таким моментом: как можно вызвать директиву из другой директивы?
Допустим, в шапке есть директива (м), которая подгружает данные, как можно показать эти данные в другой директиве, например, в подвале.

В jquery это делается просто, а здесь ступор. В Angular, конечно, есть jQlite. Может, есть другой способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать модуль с подгружаемыми данными и добавить его в обе директивы.